# How to edit the Shared roles in Sharing rules?

Tags: administration, sharing, org-wide-defaults

In sharing rule when I am trying to add new role (to share) it is not showing any edit option.
Could anyone please tell me how to achieve this.

Please find below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to change the "members of" or "shared with" properties of a rule. Instead, you need to create a new rule. If you no longer need this rule, you can delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Once the sharing rule is created, the Share with option is disabled.
Need to create a new sharing rule to include new roles or remove any roles

Comment: This is the same as the existing answer from 7+ years ago